# Grid item not spanning as specified

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to make a grid item (`.item3`) span entirely across and 3 rows down. After spanning it column wise, it won't span row wise. But if I increase the row span value to 4, it works. However the spanning is only 2 rows instead of 4. Here's the code.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background: black;
}

.item {
  display: grid;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: var(--yellow);
}

.item3 {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: span 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item3">3</div>
  <div class="item item4">4</div>
  <div class="item item5">5</div>
  <div class="item item6">6</div>
  <div class="item item7">7</div>
  <div class="item item8">8</div>
  <div class="item item9">9</div>
  <div class="item item10">10</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has no definition for the rows. Once you add that, you see the span visibly does what can be expected.

Before that, your virtual rows kind of collapsed because they themselves had no content, and were sized the default, which is `auto`.

```
grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 24px);
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 24px);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background: black;
}

.item {
  display: grid;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: var(--yellow);
}

.item3 {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: span 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item3">3</div>
  <div class="item item4">4</div>
  <div class="item item5">5</div>
  <div class="item item6">6</div>
  <div class="item item7">7</div>
  <div class="item item8">8</div>
  <div class="item item9">9</div>
  <div class="item item10">10</div>
</div>
```

I assume you are aware that a grid cell is **always rectangular**.

Answer (score 4):

There's *a lot* going on in this layout.

But, essentially, the main problem is a lack of extra height in the container.

Here's what's happening:

---

### Explicit and Implicit Rows

This is what you have:

```
.container {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
   grid-gap: 10px;
   background: black;
}

.item {
   display: grid;
   border-radius: 2px;
   border: 1px solid red;
   background-color: var(--yellow);
}

.item3 {
   grid-column: 1 / -1;
   grid-row: span 3;
}
```

The `.item` rule is having no impact on the problem, so let's just leave the borders for illustration purposes.

```
.container {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
   grid-gap: 10px;
   background: black;
}

.item3 {
   grid-column: 1 / -1;
   grid-row: span 3;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Because you haven't defined `grid-template-rows` or `grid-template-areas`, there are no *explicit* rows. All rows are *implicit* (created as needed).

The size of implicit rows is governed by `grid-auto-rows`, whose default value is `auto` (the size of the content).

So the height of each row is currently defined by the size of the text – the numbers – in your HTML.

The numbers are invisible because the background and text are both black. To better understand the source of the row height, let's change the text color to white.

```
.container {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
   grid-gap: 10px;
   background: black;
   color: white; /* new */
}
```

Here's the full code so far:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.item3 {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: span 3;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item3">3</div>
  <div class="item item4">4</div>
  <div class="item item5">5</div>
  <div class="item item6">6</div>
  <div class="item item7">7</div>
  <div class="item item8">8</div>
  <div class="item item9">9</div>
  <div class="item item10">10</div>
</div>
```

As stated above, the default height of implicit rows is `auto`. This means that if `grid-auto-rows` isn't specified, and there is no content in the grid items, the rows would collapse:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.item3 {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: span 3;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item3"></div>
  <div class="item item4"></div>
  <div class="item item5"></div>
  <div class="item item6"></div>
  <div class="item item7"></div>
  <div class="item item8"></div>
  <div class="item item9"></div>
  <div class="item item10"></div>
</div>
```

The remaining height in the container comes from the border thickness and the 10px grid gaps. Remove those for a complete collapse (the grid disappears).

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  /* grid-gap: 10px; */
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.item3 {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: span 3;
}

.item {
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item3"></div>
  <div class="item item4"></div>
  <div class="item item5"></div>
  <div class="item item6"></div>
  <div class="item item7"></div>
  <div class="item item8"></div>
  <div class="item item9"></div>
  <div class="item item10"></div>
</div>
```

---

### The Item 3 Problem

```
.item3 {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: span 3;
}
```

When you command `item3` to span across three rows, it doesn't span across the three existing rows because those tracks are occupied already. However, if you remove the `grid-column` command, then `span 3` works.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.item3 {
  /* grid-column: 1 / -1; */
  grid-row: span 3;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item3">3</div>
  <div class="item item4">4</div>
  <div class="item item5">5</div>
  <div class="item item6">6</div>
  <div class="item item7">7</div>
  <div class="item item8">8</div>
  <div class="item item9">9</div>
  <div class="item item10">10</div>
</div>
```

Let's go back to my first line for a minute: *"When you command `item3` to span across three rows, it doesn't span across the other two rows because those tracks are occupied already."*

That's true. But it's also true that two new rows *are created*. The grid simply subdivides the first row to fit three.

Here's how it looks using [Firefox's Grid Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_grid_layouts):

[image]

Notice how the first row has been divided into three, and the grid now has a total of five rows (because `span 3` = existing row + 2).

Let's make it `grid-row: span 10` for a better look:

[image]

The height of the subdivided first row is coming entirely from the `grid-gap`, which is adding 10px between each new row.

*By the way, that's the explanation for this part of your question:*

> *If I increase the row span value to 4, it works. However the spanning is only 2 rows instead of 4.*

*You're actually just seeing the effect of 10px row gaps stacking.*

If you remove the grid gap, the `span` will still generate subdivided rows, but these new rows will not change the height of the first row.

Here's the same layout with `span 10` again and no `grid-gap`:

[image]

---

### Solutions

Here are three ways to solve the problem.

**1. Give the container some height.**

If you provide extra height to the container – meaning more height than needed by the content – the `grid-row: span 3` will have some space to work.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  height: 250px; /* new */
}

.item3 {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: span 3;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item3">3</div>
  <div class="item item4">4</div>
  <div class="item item5">5</div>
  <div class="item item6">6</div>
  <div class="item item7">7</div>
  <div class="item item8">8</div>
  <div class="item item9">9</div>
  <div class="item item10">10</div>
</div>
```

**2. Define `grid-auto-rows`.**

If you set a height to `grid-auto-rows`, which controls the height of implicit rows, then `grid-row: span 3` will also work.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 50px; /* new */
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.item3 {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: span 3;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item3">3</div>
  <div class="item item4">4</div>
  <div class="item item5">5</div>
  <div class="item item6">6</div>
  <div class="item item7">7</div>
  <div class="item item8">8</div>
  <div class="item item9">9</div>
  <div class="item item10">10</div>
</div>
```

**3. Define `grid-template-rows`.**

If you know how many rows you want in the container, set number and height to `grid-template-rows`, which controls the height of explicit rows.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 50px); /* new */
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.item3 {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: span 3;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item3">3</div>
  <div class="item item4">4</div>
  <div class="item item5">5</div>
  <div class="item item6">6</div>
  <div class="item item7">7</div>
  <div class="item item8">8</div>
  <div class="item item9">9</div>
  <div class="item item10">10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Faced the same problem. Your first observation was spot on!

Answer (score -1):

You need to provide information regarding how the grid looks in terms of the rows.

Without `grid-template-rows` set on the parent, `grid-row: span 3` on the child will be calculated on an *implicit grid* and will be auto sized by default (in the height dimension).

Setting `grid-template-rows` creates an *explicit grid*.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 20px);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background: black;
}

.item {
  display: grid;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: var(--yellow);
}

.item3 {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: span 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item3">3</div>
  <div class="item item4">4</div>
  <div class="item item5">5</div>
  <div class="item item6">6</div>
  <div class="item item7">7</div>
  <div class="item item8">8</div>
  <div class="item item9">9</div>
  <div class="item item10">10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: *Without `grid-template-rows` set on the parent, `grid-row` on the child won't do anything.* That's not true. Remove your `grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 20px);` and change `grid-row: span 3;` to `grid-row: span 50;`